Custom DOE with complex constraints in JMP
Greetings fellow programmers,
I am working on customizing a DOE. I have 4 ingredients: X1, X2, X3 and X4. The lowest and highest levels of each ingredient are shown in the attached picture.
enter image description here
I have the following constraints that need to be incorporated:
•   total ingredient concentration in each recipe cannot be lower than 9.
•   total ingredient concentration in each recipe cannot be higher than 18.
•   There are can only be a maximum of 3 ingredients in each recipe.
As such, I have specified the above-mentioned constraints under the "Use Disallowed Combinations Script", as follows:
enter image description here
X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 < 9 corresponds to the 1st constraint: total ingredient concentration in each recipe cannot be lower than 9.
X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 > 18 corresponds to the 2nd constraint: total ingredient concentration in each recipe cannot be higher than 18.
(X1 * X2 * X3 * X4 > 0) corresponds to the 3rd constraint: There are can only be a maximum of 3 ingredients in each recipe.
I am specifying a response surface model with the addition of cubic and quartic terms as follows:
enter image description here
And, I am specifying a user-specified 50 runs for this design.
However, I run into an error when generating the design, as shown below:
enter image description here
After some troubleshooting, I am able to successfully generate the design with only the first two constraints (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 < 9 | X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 > 18). I cannot seem to incorporate the 3rd constraint of having not more than 3 ingredients in any recipe. Am I specifying the 3rd constraint incorrectly? Please help. I do not know how to solve this problem.
Many thanks in advance.
An additional note: I run into the error even when only specifying the 3rd constraint: (X1 * X2 * X3 * X4 > 0). Is there anything wrong with this expression?

After some troubleshooting, I am able to successfully generate the design with only the first two constraints (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 < 9 | X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 > 18). I cannot seem to incorporate the 3rd constraint of having not more than 3 ingredients in any recipe. Am I specifying the 3rd constraint incorrectly? Please help. I do not know how to solve this problem.
Many thanks in advance.
An additional note: I run into the error even when only specifying the 3rd constraint: (X1 * X2 * X3 * X4 > 0). Is there anything wrong with this expression?
